# RestKit: "multipartFormRequestWithObject" sends only attachment, object properties are lost

Tags: ios, restkit

I need to POST a **Realty** object with images:

```
-(void) addRealty:(Realty*)realty withImages:(NSDictionary*)images success:(void (^)(Realty *))callback failure:(void(^)(void))failure
{
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [_httpClient multipartFormRequestWithObject:realty method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"/realties.json" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                                        name:@"_realty[images][0]"
                                    fileName:@"test.png"
                                    mimeType:@"image/png"];
        }];

        RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [_httpClient objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
        [_httpClient enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
    }
}
```

Request is being sent to the server, however when I check my logs I see that "realty" field have only image, no other properties (price, area, etc..):

```
{"_realty"=>{"images"=>{"0"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005817f40 @original_filename="test.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"_realty[images][0]\"; filename=\"test.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140315-28741-1yvodfr>>}}}
```

Realty mappings:

```
RKObjectMapping *realtyMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Realty class]];
[realtyMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray: @[@"_id",@"user_id",@"description",@"notes",@"address",@"coords",@"pictures",@"area",@"rtype",@"rooms",@"price",@"price_m",@"title"]];

// - multiple
RKResponseDescriptor *realtiesDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:realtyMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"realties" statusCodes:statusCodes];
[_httpClient addResponseDescriptor:realtiesDescriptor];
// - single
RKResponseDescriptor *realtySingleDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:realtyMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"realty" statusCodes:statusCodes];
[_httpClient addResponseDescriptor:realtySingleDescriptor];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add RKRequestDescriptor object for **Realty**.

```
RKObjectMapping* realtyMapping = <...>;
RKRequestDescriptor* reqDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:realtyMapping
objectClass:[Realty class]
rootKeyPath:nil
method:RKRequestMethodAny];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:reqDescriptor];
```

Good luck :)

Comment: You might want to use `[realtyMapping inverseMapping]`